# How do I know when multiple threads finished (Swift)

Tags: multithreading, swift, parse-platform

I use Parse to fetch rows and each row contains a `PFFile`. I want to store fetched data into a model, in kinda this way:

```
class MyModel {
    var name: String
    var image: UIImage

    init(dataObject: PFObject) {
         self.name=dataObject["name"] as! String
         let imageFile = dataObject["image"] as! PFFile
         imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock() {
              (imageData: NSData?,error: NSError?) -> Void in
              self.image=UIImage(imageData)
         }
    }

}

func fetchData() {
    var myCollection = Array<MyModel>()
    parseQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
         (objects: [AnyObject]?,error: NSError) -> Void in
         if let parseObjects = objects as? [PFObject] {
              for parseObject in parseObjects {
                   myCollection.append(MyModel(parseObject))
              }
         }
    }
    println("Fetching finished and data loaded")
}
```

Well that 'fetching finished' is correct , but data is still not loaded because of that image fetching, how can i tell in this case if the fetching and `myCollection` object is fully loaded?

Answer (score 2):

You can use *NSOperation* + *NSOperationQueue*, like this:

```
import Foundation

let queue = NSOperationQueue()
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

for _ in 0..<10
{
    var op = NSBlockOperation( block: {
        println("do something")
    } )
    queue.addOperation( op )
}

queue.suspended = false
queue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()

println("done!")
```

Comment: still... doesn't wait the spawned threads, the problem is that in println("do something")  section i spawn a thread...

Comment: If you want simultaneous background operations, replace `maxConcurrentOperationCount` with your desired number.

Answer (score 0):

You can create variables with observers to keep counting of pending functions or a simple boolean with observer if you are just worried with one call, as the examples bellow:

Wait for just one request to finish:

```
var finishRequest:Bool{
    didSet{
        if finishRequestesFunc{
            finishReques() //call function when finish download request
        }
    }
}
```

Wait many requests to finish:

```
var counthRequests:Int{
    didSet{
        if (counthRequests == 0) {
            finishRequestesFunc() //call function when finish download request
        }
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is to set `finishRequest` to `false` before call the request function `(findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock)` and set it to `true` when it finish, as soon as it is set to true the `finishRequestesFunc` function will be called.
Similar for the count method, but here you add one before call the request function `(findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock)` and subtract one as soon as it is done, when the counter is back to zero the function `finishRequestsFunc` will be called

```
class MyModel {
    var name: String
    var image: UIImage
    var finishRequest:Bool{
         didSet{
            if finishRequestesFunc{
                finishReques() //call function when finish download request
            }
        }
    }   
    init(dataObject: PFObject) {
         self.name=dataObject["name"] as! String
         let imageFile = dataObject["image"] as! PFFile
         imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock() {
              (imageData: NSData?,error: NSError?) -> Void in
              self.image=UIImage(imageData)
         }
    }

    func fetchData() {
        finishRequest = false
        var myCollection = Array<MyModel>()
        parseQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?,error: NSError) -> Void in
            [unowned self]
            if let parseObjects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for parseObject in parseObjects {
                    myCollection.append(MyModel(parseObject))
                }
            }
            self.finishRequest = true
        }
        println("Fetching finished and data loaded")
    }

    func finishReques(){
    }
```

Comment: Well interesting... but is there no other solution? Because for this too work i need to give reference or declare static var so my MyModel class initializer will decrease the counthRequests variable...?

Comment: I don't see why you need a static variable, the solution is on the post above, I couldn't test as I am in a Windows machine now but It should be right

Comment: fetchData is in some view controller and MyModel class has only properties and that initializer in it

Comment: ..and i guess u misunderstood, fetchData is called kinda once...the problem is with the for loop, which execute initializers, and part of initializer is entering into a new thread. So the loop will iterate all objects, while that threads spawned by the initializer will maybe still running

Comment: I don't think you need a counter but an boolean, sorry I am a bit confuse in what problem you are seem, my opinion is don't fetch data from the view is bad practice, just create an object and call a function that do the fetch for you. That is what I would do, I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

First, a general answer:

Grand Central Dispatch has the concept of dispatch groups. There are methods like dispatch_group_create and dispatch_group_notify that let you keep track of a set of blocks and trigger a separate block once the group is done.

That doesn't seem applicable to your problem though, since you're using a third party library (parse).

What I would do is to create an instance variable called something like remainingTasks. When you get ready to start a task that needs to do multiple things in the background, set it to the number of sub-tasks that need to run. In the completion handler for each task, decrement the count. Then add a didSet method to the instance variable, as @IcaroNZ suggests. Once the remainingTasks drops to zero you know you're done and can go on.

Comment: And why/so i can't say: there is thread A, execute and bound thread a,b,c,d to thread A?